# How can I make should.js assertions about dates?

Tags: javascript, should.js

I've got a unit test like this:

```
(parsed.date).should.equal(new Date(2006,06,18,18,07));
```

Which fails with this message:

```
  AssertionError: expected 2006-07-19T00:07:00.000Z to be 2006-07-19T00:07:00.000Z
  + expected - actual
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found it - I should be comparing dates with `eql` not `equal`.

Working code:

```
(parsed.date).should.eql(new Date(2006,06,18,18,07));
```

More at this link: https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/issues/63 specifically comment https://github.com/visionmedia/should.js/issues/63#issuecomment-27626023